# Yii - I want to show either "Login" or "Logout" in an HTML menu

Tags: php, html, yii, menu, html-lists

I am using a custom HTML menu, not the 'zii.widgets.CMenu'. I want to only show 1 list item

for the Login/Logout. I would like to use the code:

For Login:

```
'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
```

And for Logout:

```
'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
```

Is this possible? Where do I put it? I have used the below code to display the user name when logged in and it works:

```
<?= Yii::app()->user->name?>
```

Here is the menu's code:
    
            
                
                
                    
                        Toggle navigation
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    Brand

```
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="dashboard">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Auctions <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="tbauctionitem/create">Add Action</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="auctionsearch">Search Action</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="tbauctionitem/admin">Manage Auctions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="site/logout">Logout <?= Yii::app()->user->name?></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work for you?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
    <?php
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
    {
        ?><a href="login">Login</a><?php
    } else {
        ?><a href="site/logout">Logout <?= Yii::app()->user->name?></a><?php
    }
    ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```